# Bouldering vs aid climbing vs free climbing vs free solo climbing

Tags: rock-climbing, bouldering, free-solo-climbing, free-climbing, aid-climbing

What re the differences between these 4 styles of rock climbing?

- Bouldering
- Aid Climbing
- Free Climbing
- Free solo climbing

Comment: Related meta entry: [Community wiki on climbing styles](http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/606/community-wiki-on-climbing-styles)

Comment: You could add *deep-water soloing*, and *free-basing* to this question.

Comment: @Shem Never heard of *free-basing*, I just find drug related topics: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Freebasing Also I wouldn't extend too much. *Deep-water soloing* is free soloing but just over water. As one of the origins of free climbing we could also add [Saxon Switzerland climbing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saxon_Switzerland#Rock_climbing) and so on ;)

Comment: Yeah, that's a chemistry term isn't it, not just drugs...Anyway I digress.

Comment: Free-basing is bigwall soloing with a parachute.

Comment: Dean Potter is the first guy to freebase, [watch this video to learn more about it](https://youtu.be/iqEkFBNiP3c).

Comment: ah, yeah. I saw this on a film about yoesmite bit wall climbing @ShemSeger. Feel free to add it to the wiki answer, below.

Comment: gerrit has also posted an excellent answer to this in his response to "http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/7586/if-the-dawn-walls-been-climbed-before-why-is-the-current-attempt-so-difficult"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All of the above are styles of rock climbing. The differences/similarities are highlighted below:

### Bouldering

- Low-level climbing (usually up to about 3m) without the use of a
  rope.
- Falls are typically protected against by the use of large portable
  mats (bouldering mats).
- Concentrates on technically difficult short climbs.
- Usually (though not exclusively) performed on boulders, as opposed to cliff faces (hence the name).

[image]

### Aid Climbing

- Uses ropes.
- The rock itself is climbed utilising special ladder-like equipment
  called "aiders".
- Items of equipment are placed onto or into the rock face and an aider is attached. The climber then climbs the aider.
- Part of the climbing may be done using hands and feet, but at least some portions use aid.
- At least in Europe it is also called *technical climbing*.
- One of the earliest forms of rock climbing coming out of the alpinist movement of the 1930s.
- With enough effort practically *everything* can be climbed. Therefore countermovement of free climbing evolved in the 1970s.
- *"Siege tactics"* can be used. This can involve people taking months to climb difficult climbs, coming up and down at will (see the [1958 climb by Warren Harding and team to climb the 3,000 foot "Nose" of El Capitan in Yosemite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_rock_climbing#1950s))

[image]

### Free Climbing

- What most non-climbers think climbing is.
- Uses ropes.
- Climber climbs using hands and feet only. Using aid to climb on can be considered "cheating" and will [degrade the climb to an aid climb](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/6657/what-does-it-mean-to-free-a-climbing-route).
- Gear is placed in the rock face to protect against falling only, but is not used to help the climber in gaining height.
- Free climbing may be [trad or sport](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4635/whats-the-difference-between-sport-climbing-and-traditional-climbing), single-pitch or multi-pitch.

[image]

### Free solo climbing

- Climbing without rope or protection whatsoever in height where a fall will [most likely kill you](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/8106/how-far-would-you-need-to-fall-for-it-to-be-fatal).
- Falls can be fatal and no attempt is made to protect against falling and hitting the ground.
- Considered the most dangerous of all climbing styles.
- An Especially psychological variety of climbing.

[image]